# Redirecting login page using AuthenticationSuccessHandler in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I am trying to find the best way to redirect a form on successful login to a particular page based on the select option the user selected on login. I don't know if this is the best way, so please help with your suggestions.

This is my solution so:

```
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        //return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/");
        return (request, response, authentication)-> {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if(session != null){
                request.setAttribute("program","program");
                if(request.getAttribute("program") != null) {
                    response.sendRedirect("/cert-prog");
                }
            }
            response.sendRedirect("/");
        };
    }
```

This the part of my form I am using as a select option:

```
     <select class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled">[Select Program Type]</option>
                    <option th:each="program : ${programs}" th:value="${program.values}" th:text="${program.name}" >Certificate programs</option>
                </select>
```

My login form:

```
    <form class="myform" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control input-lg">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled">[Select Program Type]</option>
                <option th:each="program : ${programs}" th:value="${program.values}" th:text="${program.name}" >Certificate programs</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="LoginID" th:field="*{username}" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" />
            </div>
        </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon form-wrapper" id="sizing-addon2">@</span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control showpassword" placeholder="Pin" th:field="*{password}"  aria-describedby="sizing-addon1"  />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default toggle" type="button">Show Pin</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox" /> <p class="login-caution">I have carefully read all instructions as well as programme requirements in the Admission Brochure and i here my accept any responsibility for any omission(s) or error(s) on my submitted form.</p>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="btnCheck" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
    </form>
```

`LoginController.java`

```java
    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String loginForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
            model.addAttribute("user", new User());
           // model.addAttribute("programs", Programs.values());
            try {
                Object flash = request.getSession().getAttribute("flash");
                model.addAttribute("flash", flash);

                request.getSession().removeAttribute("flash");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // "flash" session attribute must not exist...do nothing and proceed normally
            }
            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/access_denied")
        public String accessDenied() {
            return "access_denied";
        }
    }
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
            auth.userDetailsService(userService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                        .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
                        .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
                        .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        }

        //Certificate-program"
        public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
            //return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/");
//What i am trying to do...Need your help here
            return (request, response, authentication) -> {
                if(request.getSession().getAttribute("programs").equals("Certificate-program")){
                    response.sendRedirect("company");
                }else {
                    response.sendRedirect("/");
                }
            };
        }

        public AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
            return (request, response, exception) -> {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Incorrect username and/or password. Please try again.", FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
                response.sendRedirect("/login");
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Spring security's form-login the request for a secured resource is stored, and when login is completed the original request is restored and processed. In my opinion your approach to use a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is a good way to redirect after successful authentication.

However there is one small thing you forgot. If you look at the source code for `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, which is used by default for form-login, you will notice that it removes the saved request from the `RequestCache`, you should do the same or saved request continues to exist in the users session.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I have read a lot about it but my implementation is still not working. See question